# how to define the Path of an audio file

Tags: java, eclipse

hi i am a new java programmer. i am just trying to create a media player of my own, i have written the coding but i dont know to define the path of file to be played.
Pls help me in defining the path of an audio file to be played in a java program which is configured in Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String path = "C:\\somefolder\\song.mp3";
```

If you were looking for something more please clarify the question.

Comment: sample code will throw compiler error.!! It must be String path = "C:\\somefolder\\song.mp3";